# Installing Perl with Perlbrew

Tags: perl, installation, perlbrew

I am trying to install Perl version 5.19.2 or version 5.19.8 with perlbrew. I am using the following command to install:

`perlbrew -v install perl-5.19.8 (or 5.19.2) -Dcc=gcc`

Everytime no matter what version I am trying to install I keep getting the following error:

`FatPacker error loading Devel/PatchPerl.pm (could be a perl installation issue?) at /Path/to/my/perl/bin/patchperl line 33687`

I am not sure whats going on. I am not very experienced in Perl. If anyone can offer me some tips/help that will be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Try deleting `patchperl` (which is to say renaming it for backup purposes) then running `perlbrew install-patchperl`. Sounds like got corrupted.

Comment: No it tried that before, does not help.

Comment: Try deleting `patchperl`. Period. (Restore it after you've installed the desired Perl.) There [no patches](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BINGOS/Devel-PatchPerl-1.16/lib/Devel/PatchPerl.pm) for 5.19.x

Comment: Okay following your suggestion I was able to replicate the actual PerlBrew internal command line, the line that PerlBrew actually uses to make and install Perl and run it after taking out the Patchperl command. That seems to solve the issue